# Removing index.php from Oxwall URLs

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've just installed Oxwall (oxwall.org) on my shared 1and1 host and would like to remove "index.php" from all URLs.

> Essentially PHP needs to see this
>   http://site.com/index.php/Page/Param1/Param2
>
> While I want the user to see this 
>   http://site.com/Page/Param1/Param2

I understand this should be done using the .htaccess file, but I don't know how to do it...

Currently, .htaccess file looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

AddEncoding gzip .gz
AddEncoding gzip .gzip
<FilesMatch "\.(js.gz|js.gzip)$">
  ForceType text/javascript
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(css.gz|css.gzip)$">
  ForceType text/css
</FilesMatch>

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !oxwall.(host).com$

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/ow_updates/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/ow_updates/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/ow_cron/run\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.xml|\.feed|robots\.txt|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
```

Any suggestions?
I've found similar messages on stackoverflow, but I wasn't able to apply the proposed fixes to my .htaccess file...

Thank you very much for your time and support!

Answer (score -1):

Found the solution!
Simply used the htaccess code mentionned in this topic: http://www.oxwall.org/forum/topic/7924

Hope this helps others!